# What are "Straight Corner Fixing Brackets" used for?

Tags: brackets

I saw these on eBay. What is their intended use? I was able to find lots of photos of similar items on Google but not of their actual use case.

They seem to be for use against a flush surface. When would this bracket me useful compared to using screws alone?

[image]

Comment: what else do you see when you google `straight corner fixing brackets`?

Comment: the name is probably confusing ..... it is  `corner fixing bracket` that is straight  .... think about picture frames .... http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_PlPmCtNJTV8/TJdv5GX_4DI/AAAAAAAAAKc/zP52CDGXtx0/s1600/img_0067.jpg

Comment: Too broad. The answer is almost limitless. Voting to close.

Comment: @jsotola answers down there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be installed in various ways. You can install them to join corners straight from one surface to the other, or diagonally from one surface to the other. You can also use them in a situation where you want to allow the expansion/contraction or slight movement of a fixture. This would allow say a table top to expand or contract with temperature or humidity changes. This would then keep the table top from cracking.